# Can I Store KDB OS Command Output into an Object?

Tags: kdb

I'm new to KDB and I'm looking at it from a security stand point.

Can I run a combination of a DB query and an OS command as a one liner?
Or, can I store the OS command's output to a DB object?

I've been playing around with KDB Q, but either it's not possible or
I haven't found the proper syntax.

Thank you

Comment: I wanted to post some of my new findings. I can piggyback queries like so: select from family where name = `John; system "ipconfig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see below:

```
q)update res:system each cmd from ([] cmd:("uptime";"date";"uname -a"))
    cmd        res
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "uptime"   " 21:01:03 up 31 days,  6:54,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.00"
    "date"     "Fri 17 Mar 21:01:03 GMT 2017"
    "uname -a" "Linux glyph01 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
```

Running a system command is more or less the same as running any other function in Kdb+.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I'll give this a try.